# How do I save a property of type Class with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

More specificly, how do I save a list of type class with Hibernate?

I have the following (simplefied) class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bundles")
public class Bundle{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private List<Class<?>> classes;

    // Getters & Setters and some logic
}
```

Now, how do I go about saving this in a database? I need a database schema wich provides an option to save a "class" type, but I can't figure it out. I use PostgreSQL as a database.

The fact that it is a List would not really matter, I would just annotate it with @OneToMany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-basic-value-class), `Class<?>` is correctly handled by hibernate:

> 6.1.1.20. java.lang.Class
>
> org.hibernate.type.ClassType
>   Maps a java.lang.Class to a JDBC VARCHAR (using the Class name)
>
> Registered under class and java.lang.Class in the type registry (see Section 6.5, “Type registry”).

The database "column" needs to be `VARCHAR`